# Whitespace in first array position with myString.split("\\s+")

Tags: java

So I have a string:

```
String myString = "[tab][space]this[space][tab]is[space]a[space][tab]string";
String[] mySplit = myString.split("\\s+");

System.out.println(mySplit.length);
for (String s : mySplit) 
    System.out.println(s);
```

Gives me:

```
5
[whitespace] 
this
is
a
string
```

Why is this and how do I stop that first position from being filled with whitespace?

Comment: Are you sure mySplit[0] is a whitespace and not an empty string?

Comment: It would be an empty string but println adds a new-line. I think that's what the poster is referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `split()` is defined, if the input string starts with the delimiter then the first returned segment will be empty.  This might be a little counter-intuitive, but consider

```
String value = ",a,b,c";
String[] fields = value.split(",");
```

You would want to get back four elements.

If you need to remove leading whitespace then use `trim()` first.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand why it would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
myString.trim().split("\\s+");
```

This should trim off any leading or trailing white space before splitting the string on whitespace. See the [documentation for `trim`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that split finds all substrings terminated by your regex, including the empty string. It is finding the "\t " at the beginning of your string and interpreting it as terminating an empty string. Therefore your array contains an empty string as the first element. Paul's suggestion fixes this issue.

What is interesting is that if your string ends with a space, split will not include an empty string in your array.

See [javadoc for split.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: +1 for nice explanation and mentioning that the `split(String)` overload discards trailing empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think the function your are looking to do this is `trim()`.

**First trim the String...**

```
String myString = "[tab][space]this[space][tab]is[space]a[space][tab]string";
String tempStr = myString.trim();
```

**Now use the split()**

`tempStr.split("\\s+");`

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use trim() method which is  used to remove the leading and trailing white spaces.